# How to Start/Stop/Delete the user define services from MS-CONFIG

Tags: windows, windows-services

I am running the Spring-Boot application as a Windows service.I can see my services is listed in the MSCONFIG

[image]

I wanted to know how can I

- Stop
- Start
- Delete

The Service.

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform those operations from MSCONFIG. Use the [services control panel application (services.msc)](https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/essential-tools-windows-services-msc/) to start, stop and generally manage your service. Use the SC command line utility to delete your service ("SC DELETE service-name").